# Can I determent typename T* in template is a array or object?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, templates

I have a `T* data` under  `template <typename T>`.
Is that any possible way for me to know that T* is an object or an array so that I can use `delete` and `delete[]` properly?

Comment: Short Answer: Nope.

Comment: Are you asking A) is `T` either something like `int*` or like  `int[8]` and known at compile time, or B) at runtime, given any `T*`, was it allocated with `new` or with `new[]`, assuming it was heap allocated at all? A) can be solved easily, B) is not possible to solve.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Assuming you're creating some kind of data structure, does it own the pointer? Did it allocate the pointer, or did it receive the pointer from elsewhere?

Comment: You can specialize the template for array types and call `delete[]` in that specialization.

Comment: I think that my question is about allocated a pointer with new or with new[]. Someone tell me that I may be allowed to deterrent it by typeid. Is this possible?